# cvs2svn crash before end

Tags: crash, cvs2svn, svndump

I ran `cvs2svn` a couple of times successfully.
Now I ran it and it crashed just before the end, at pass 16.

I'm using dumpfile.

I get the following error : 
[alt text http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/1079/73784110.jpg](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/1079/73784110.jpg)

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the current version of cvs2svn, namely release 2.3.0.

Under Windows, you also have to make sure you have the correct locale set, as described in [this bug report](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=114).

If you still have problems, you should report this as a bug to [the cvs2svn users mailing list](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=1670).  Please include a reproducible test case as described in [the FAQ](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#reportingbugs).

Comment: I've upgraded cvs2svn 2.3.0 and python version to 2.6 and it works perfectly and faster ! 


thanks.