# cvs2svn 2.3.0 crashes in pass 16

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

I've posted a question regarding cvs2svn crashes ([link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361257/cvs2svn-crash-before-end)).

I was suggested to update to cvs2svn v2.3.0 and so I did and it worked.

now suddenly cvs2svn crashes again before the end,
[alt text http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/1592/cvs2svnerror1.jpg](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/1592/cvs2svnerror1.jpg)

what can be the problem again?
I'm using dump file.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion requires more RAM than is available in your computer.  Consider using a computer with more RAM, stopping other programs while you run the conversion, or configuring swap space.

Comment: why do you think that?
I've converted a much bigger repository (~60,000 revisions) with no problem...

Comment: The amount of memory used by cvs2svn doesn't only depend on the number of revisions.  It also depends on things like the size of the largest file, the number of CVS file revisions, the number of files in the repository, number of symbols, etc.  MemoryError definitely indicates an out-of-memory situation of some sort; either exhaustion of RAM+swap or (if you are using a 32-bit computer) exhaustion of the virtual address space.